# Segmentation fault during Laravel Migration

Tags: php, laravel, segmentation-fault

**The problem**

[image]

As per my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118300/laravel-ignoring-fields-that-dont-exist-when-using-modelcreate/53118466#comment93131380_53118466), it was pointed out to me that I shouldn't be trying to fill related models in a Laravel Factory (i.e I should fill them in their own factory).

However, I have an observer that looks for the related data during the creation and tries to fill related models (this is so I can create multiple related entities using just the `create::` method and a single multistep form). Now, I need to add a check to see if this data is populated in the observer so I don't have to specify it in the factory.

In doing so, I now get a segmentation fault when trying to seed my database. I've narrowed down the cause to this line - without the `isset` check, it works fine (other than $data['day'] is not specified, hence the check);

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
if(isset($data['day'])) $event->day->fill($data['day']);
```

**Related Code**

EventFactory.php

```
$factory->define(App\Event::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        "name"                        => "A Test Event",
        "description"                 => $faker->paragraphs(3, true),
        "event_start_date"            => today(),
        "event_opening_date"          => today(),
        "event_closing_date"          => tomorrow(),
        "user_id"                     => 1,
        "banner_id"                   => 1,
        "gallery_id"                  => 1,
        "related_event_id"            => 1,
        "status"                      => "published",
        "purchase_limit"              => 1000,
        "limit_remaining"             => 1000,
        "delivery_method"             => "collection",
        "merchandise_delivery_method" => "collection"
    ];
});
```

EventObserver.php

```
public function created($event){
        # get all attributes
        $data = $event->getAttributes();

        # fill any related models
        if(isset($data['day'])) $event->day->fill($data['day']);

        # save user
        $event->push();
    }

public function updating($model){
        # get all attributes
        $data = $model->getAttributes();

        # fill any related models
        if(isset($data['day'])) $model->day->fill($data['day']);

        # save user
        $model->push();
    }
```

**Other Info**

> Command: sudo php artisan migrate:reset --seed
>
> Host: Windows 10
>
> VM Environment: Vagrant running Ubuntu 16.04 via HyperV, mounted share with Samba
>
> PHP Version: 7.1.20
>
> Laravel Version: 5.7

## Update

Turns out the issue is actually with this line;

`$event->push();`

Could there be something recursive happening here?

## Update 2

With Namoshek's help, I can now narrow it down to the following error from xdebug;

> Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!

Increasing xdebug.max_nesting_level to 200000 brings back the segfault.

This seems to me like it's stuck in an infinite loop. However, I can't see how calling `save()` or `push()` in `created` would end up calling back to itself. Confused.

Comment: did you check the memories ? both RAM and disk ?

Comment: @volkovmqx According to htop, memory never reaches max. Iotop shows low disk usage while seeding.

Comment: Have you tried saving the related model as well as the `$event` manually with `save()` instead of `push()`?

Comment: @Namoshek Same issue with save() unfortunately

Comment: I think maxing out the RAM would be a different error.  This is an interesting one, segmentation faults are rare in Php.  Are you handling any variables in this process by-reference?  (I know objects always are anyway.)  About the only way I've been able to trigger a segmentation fault by by basically confusing Php as to where the internal-pointer is on an array.

Comment: You could try increasing the `pcre.recursion_limit` within your `php.ini`. If this helps, you'd know it is a recursion problem. You can also decrease its value to see if PHP terminates with a different error. Because if the recursion limit is reached, the process will simply crash instead of terminating gracefully.

Comment: @Claymore unfortunately I don't know enough about the internals of Laravel to know for sure but I think $event itself may be passed by reference

Comment: Objects are always passed by reference in PHP.

Comment: @Namoshek interesting. Reducing the `pcre.recursion_limit` to  `1` and increasing it to `1000000` made no difference to the error.

Comment: Then I think you should get out xdebug to find the exact crash point.

Comment: @Namoshek Thanks for the pointer! With xdebug installed, it now shows `Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!` I can't quite follow the flow well enough to see where this happens. I can't see how calling `save()` or `push()` on `created` would do this, as both save() and push should update, I think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183014/discussion-between-namoshek-and-lewis).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This did indeed turn out to be an infinite recursion issue. Eliminating the line:

```
$event->push(); // this line appears to call update again, which in turn calls push, which calls update etc...
```

Solved the problem.

Comment: Its not work for me.